# How to return to flutter App after a call using launchUrlString

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, url-launcher

My IOS mobile App has option to call using following function.

The function  activated by button tapped

```
  Function callTapped() {
     launchUrlString('tel://${mobile.toString()}');
```

}

How can I return to the App after the call?

How can I add a back button?

Comment: Is call from app itself or IOS default call option?

Comment: @JenishMS I am guessing it's from the default call option since it's launching like an url and OP wants user to return to the app; meaning that he left.

Comment: @JenishMS MS  called from my App